# How can you build React on top of Drupal?

Tags: reactjs, drupal, content-management-system

I've never used Drupal, but have been looking up tutorials online. My client would really like the adaptability of React and to have more flexibility in terms of design. I could make my own database and React app, but I have not studied security (I'm a team of one, so no one for security on my end, either). Security and access to a content management system was the main reason we decided to go with Drupal. However, I would still like to be able to code in React/something I'm familiar with to produce a site I am proud to say I made.

I've been Googling and Youtubing tutorials and help, but not having anyone to ask specific questions is making this difficult.

If anyone knows of a relatively easy way to build a React app on Drupal, I would really appreciate the advice. Or if there is a better way I should go about beginning a project as I've briefly mentioned above, I would also be open to that. Thank you in advance and sorry for the long message!

Answer (score 0):

What you are asking is quite broad in concept and not easy to answer in just one answer post. Try to look for Headless / Decoupled Drupal.

https://www.acquia.com/drupal/decoupled-drupal

What this essentially means is that all the services and the content management are handled by Drupal while the core user experience or the way the site is displayed in a browser is controlled via a JavaScript framework such as React.js or backbone.js. This is achieved via Drupal’s RESTful API service.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you for the information and sorry I took so long to respond! I realized how broad the question was once I attempted to build them. Honestly, the decoupled/headless Drupal concepts are a bit confusing since I know relatively nothing about Drupal. However, I'm working on figuring out Drupal and then maybe the concepts will make more sense.